# Collapsible data columns in table using jquery/javascript.

Tags: jquery, css, html, html-table

[Table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKEJR.png)

As you can see in the image, some of the table data has 2 main columns headers(th) while others have single. I am having trouble creating something for the project where if you click on **th** all the corresponding **td** collapses into vertical form (*like it does in any accordion but only vertical instead of horizontal*).

P.S I have tried creating a little mathematical program where all the corresponding **td** upon click of the **th** are highlighted.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dHKgn/27`

```
    var colspan = 0;
    var news = 0;
    var stuff = $(this).prevAll("th").each(function () {
        news = $(this).attr("colspan");
        news = parseInt(news);
        colspan = colspan + news;
    })
    indexofthis = parseInt(indexofthis);
    var total = colspan + indexofthis;
    colspan = colspan + 1;
    }

    for (var i = colspan; i <= total; i++) {
        $("td:nth-child(" + i + ")").css({
            "color": "red"
        });
    }
});`
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dHKgn/33/

Comment: Could you not separate the tables?

Comment: I am sorry I will have to do all the stuff in one table to maintain the consistency.